# Multiselect attribute in back-end should show as dropdown in front-end

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

Okay , so I want something like this

[image]

and in the back-end I want to have the attribute(Marime -- size) showing as multi-select when adding/editing an product.

How can I make this work? I'm using magento 1.9.3.